# Is someone on L2 visa in the US allowed to stay or travel without spousal L1 partner?

Tags: dependent-visa

1. Can a L2 visa holder stay back in US while the L1 spouse travels out of the country on work for a few weeks/months?
2. Can a L2 visa holder travel alone out of US and return alone while the L1 spouse continues working in the US?

Comment: 1. As long as the L-1 spouse does not abandon L-1 status, I think so.  2. Sure, why not?  Disclaimer: this answer is based on my understanding of general principles of US immigration policies, not specific knowledge of or research into these visa types.  Hence the decision to post it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. Yes

As long as L1 is in status, so is L2.

Comment: Apparently, in some scenarios, #1 is construed as "parking" and not allowed. I'd like to know if there is a threshold L1 presence criteria for this. e.g. 50% of the time per annum http://www.murthy.com/2013/01/21/murthychat-senior-attorney-answers-your-questions-25/

Comment: @ottodidakt as long as L1 is in status - L2 is in status. I'm not familiar with the concept of "parking". Where did you find it?

Comment: Please see link in my earlier comment. Also the section "Truly dependent visa" here: http://www.immihelp.com/l1-visa/l2-visa.html

Comment: "*if the L-1 is no longer living and working in the United States, the L-2 must leave or change to a new immigration status*" - yeah, because L1 is no longer in status. Which is exactly what I said.

Comment: Not disputing what you said. You asked about "parking". Hence the links.

Comment: Hi, any help here please? https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12052/requirements-for-b-and-l1-visa Thanks